# Derivation of (glu)lookAt

Tags: opengl, opengl-3, glulookat

I am trying to learn (modern) OpenGL and I am thoroughly confused about the various transformations...

The viewing matrix have me confused so I need some clarification.

Here's what I have understood about the (conventional) pipeline.

1. Vertices are specified in **world space**, which are scaled, translated, rotated etc. to the required positions using the **modelling** matrix
2. (Here's where I start to get confused) We can (optionally) position a virtual camera in the required location using a "lookAt" function (gluLookAt). I followed the derivation of the matrix here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9FhcvjM7Hk. I understood until the point, where the professor calculates the "look-at" vector. He says that the look-at vector = eye - center. Now here is where I begin to get lost. My first instinct is that the vector should be center - eye. Suppose the center vector is supplied as (0,0,0) and the eye vector is (0,0,5). To look at the object, the camera should point towards center - eye = (0,0,-5). However, the professor states that we want to move center - eye to the -z direction (what does that mean?). Therefore, eye - center will give the look at direction. *I am confused about this*. He further adds on that in OpenGL there is a camera at the origin looking at (0,0,-1). Now, this is I completely do not understand. I do understand that the viewing transformation is nothing but applying inverse transformation on the objects. I experimented a little bit and found that when I drew a triangle with a z-value of 1(and absolutely no modelview/projection transforms), it was still drawn on the screen. However, I wouldn't expect this to be so, since the camera is at the origin.

Now, to sum up...

- Why is look at = eye - center?
- What is this about the camera being at the origin and looking at z=-1?

Any explanations/pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you render a triangle, the vertices' coordinates are interpreted as follows:

- The x-coordinate will influence the horizontal position on the viewport. -1 is the left edge and +1 is the right edge.
- The y-coordinate will influence the vertical position on the viewport. -1 is the bottom edge and +1 is the top edge.
- The z-coordinate will influence the depth information. -1 is the position at the camera's plane (near) and +1 is the far plane. This value is usually used to write to the depth-buffer.

That's why your simple example renders a visible triangle at the far plane.

Now let's come to the view transformation. The transformation will be constructed from four vectors. The image of (1, 0, 0), the image of (0, 1, 0), the image of (0, 0, 1) and a translation vector. However, since the view transformation is an inverse transformation, the resulting matrix has to be inverted.

You are right that the view direction is `center - eye`. However, that is not what we need for the matrix. We need the image of (0, 0, 1). Usually, OpenGL programs use a right-handed coordinate system. In that system the camera looks into negative z-direction. So `center - eye` is actually the image of (0, 0, -1). The image of (0, 0, 1) is then just `eye - center`. That's what you need.

With this definition you will also need an appropriate projection transformation. Otherwise you will only see things behind the camera (because that's where the z-coordinate is positive and, hence, have a positive depth value). The projection transformation is responsible for turning negative z-coordinates into positive depth values.

Comment: I experimented a bit further, and drew two triangles, one with a z value of 1 and another with -1. The one with z value of 1 showed up in front of that with -1 (I enabled the depth buffer). That seems  sort of contradictory to your answer. 

About the derivation of gluLookAt and the perspective transformation, why would one follow such a convention? Instead of that, can't both the viewing and projection matrices have a positive z-value?

Comment: I was wrong about the range of the depth values. It's actually from -1 to 1. But still -1 is in front of 1. Are you sure that your test is valid (i.e. `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)` and absolutely no model view and projection transformation?). My quick tests yielded  the expected results (tri with higher z-value is behind tri with lower z-value). Btw, tris with z-value of 1 are already clipped, so I used a slightly lower value. Of course you can use view and projection transformations with positive z-values (i.e. left-handed coordinate system). But both transformations have to fit to each other.

Comment: Furthermore, make sure that you request a depth buffer when creating a window. Otherwise you can't store depth information and the triangle drawn last will be always on top.

Comment: Ooops, I made a mistake in the `glEnable` call. You're right, the near plane is -1 and far plane is +1. Does this mean the clip-space is left-handed in OpenGL (by default)?

Comment: Yes, that's basically what it means.

Answer (score -1):

When using a virtual camera, one usually defines an **eye space**. This definition can be arbitraty, but there are some widespread conventions (and the old matrix stack of the GL defined or preferred some of the conventions). `gluLookAt` is specified for the following convention:

1. the camera is placed at the origin
2. the camera looks at the negative z direction, +x is the right axis and +y is the up direction (so we have a right-handed coordinate system)

You should be aware that the `world space` does not really matter when rendering. All what matters is the relative placement of the objects relative to the virtual camera/eye (and that is also why old GL matrix stack has a combined `ModelView` matrix, and not two separate matrices for `Model` and `View` transfroms). Using a world space where all the objects are placed and specifying a virtual camera in that space is just more intuitive. And that is what `gluLookAt` is supposed to do. If you leave the `view` matrix at Identity, it is as if your camera is at world space origin, looking into -z direction. So to get the effect of moving the camera to some specified eye point, it is the same as moving all objects in that world space in the *inverse* direction. Same is true for rotations. And `gluLookAt` will just set up a rotation and a translation. Have a look at [my previous answer about `gluLookAt`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16264698/about-lookat-function/16264932#16264932) for some of the details.

Comment: Thanks, but this still does not answer my question; why is my triangle  being drawn? If the camera is indeed at the origin, then shouldn't a triangle of z-value = 1 be behind the camera?